# Loop through images and take user input for data label (value from 1-3)

Tags: python

I'm trying to manually label some images directly based on personal preference (ints from 1-3) so that I can use this on a learning personalization project w/ a CNN.

Any suggestions for how I can try to do this in Python? I tried the below, but what ends up happening is that the image doesn't close itself and loop to the next one once I've put in my label. Instead, I have to manually click out of the viewer window.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from shutil import copyfile
import sys

#define folders 
data_src = "data/Photos/"
one_label = "data/one_label"
two_label = "data/two_label"
three_label = "data/three_label"

extensionsToCheck = ['jpg', 'png']

listing = os.listdir(data_src)
print("src file subdirectories: ", listing)

def userInput( file_name):
    user_input = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if(user_input=='1'):
        print("don't care")
        copyfile(data_src+file_name, one_label+'/'+file_name)
    elif(user_input=='2'):
        print("neutral")
        copyfile(data_src+file_name, two_label+'/'+file_name)
    elif(user_input=='3'):
        print("like")
        copyfile(data_src+file_name, three_label+'/'+file_name)
    elif(user_input=="e"):
        print("exit")
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        return    

def main():
    print("size of dir is: ", len(listing))
    for file in listing:
        print("file: ", file)
        if any(ext in file for ext in extensionsToCheck):
            plt.figure(file)
            img=mpimg.imread(data_src + '/' + file)
            imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
            plt.title(file)
            mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
            mng.full_screen_toggle()
            plt.show()

            user_input = userInput(file)
            plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Comment: Could you try plt.close('all')?

Answer (score 1):

While image is shown, python execution gets paused, meaning that it doesn't accept user input until you manually close the image. However, you can build a GUI using tkinter or PyQt to display the image along with 1,2,and 3 buttons.

**UPDATE**

Upon further researching, I found that plt has tools `plt.ion()` and `plt.pause()` to enable interactive mode during plotting. However, you will have to manually click on the terminal to enter your classification number (1,2,3)

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from shutil import copyfile
import sys

#define folders 
data_src = "data/Photos/"
one_label = "data/one_label"
two_label = "data/two_label"
three_label = "data/three_label"

extensionsToCheck = ['jpg', 'png']

listing = os.listdir(data_src)
print("src file subdirectories: ", listing)

def userInput( file_name):
    user_input = input()
    if(user_input=='1'):
        print("don't care")
        copyfile(data_src+file_name, one_label+'/'+file_name)
        print("here")
    elif(user_input=='2'):
        print("neutral")
        copyfile(data_src+file_name, two_label+'/'+file_name)
    elif(user_input=='3'):
        print("like")
        copyfile(data_src+file_name, three_label+'/'+file_name)
    elif(user_input=="e"):
        print("exit")
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        return  0  

def main():
    print("size of dir is: ", len(listing))
    for file in listing:
        print("file: ", file)
        if any(ext in file for ext in extensionsToCheck):
            plt.figure(file)
            img=plt.imread(data_src + '/' + file)
            imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
            plt.title(file)
            #I disabled the 2 lines below because you viewing the image in full screen will prevent you from accessing the terminal to enter the classification number
            # mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
            # mng.full_screen_toggle()

            plt.ion()  #Turn the interactive mode on.
            plt.show()
            plt.pause(0.001) #Pause for interval seconds.
            user_input = userInput(file)
            plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Good luck!

Comment: Was hoping to be able to do the labeling without buttons, and do it just from the command line (i.e. type 1, then it goes to the next pic, then type 3, next pic, etc)

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on how it can be done without having to click on the terminal again? Perhaps loading the viewer first and updating the plot without reloading the window?